# Taskbar freezes, can't restart explorer.exe

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, start-menu

My taskbar occasionally freezes, also, if I end `explorer.exe` via Task Manager it doesn't seem to restart, it's just gone. How can I fix this?

Edit: I noticed this usually happens when I lock my screen then unlock after a few minutes.

Comment: The question is not clear. When it freezes? Does taskbar disappear when you end `explorer.exe` or it stays frozen? (Also ending explorer will not restart it, in Task Manager open File menu, run explorer.exe from there to start it)

Comment: @Jet It freezes occasionally I don't know what causes it, so I end it. BTW I remember Windows XP automatically restarts explorer.exe when I end it so I was expecting the same with Windows 7.

Comment: After you end-task, you can ctrl-alt-del and start taskmgr again, then use its File > New Task (run)  to start a new instance of "Explorer.exe". But it would be better to find out what is causing your taskbar to freeze!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, you should figure out what's causing the Taskbar to freeze. Have you installed any custom shell extensions, deskbands, etc?

To launch a new explorer process, you can press Ctrl+Alt+Del, then find explorer.exe process, right click it and select End all processes. Then go to File > New Task (run) and type explorer.exe and click OK. Wait a few seconds and it should be ok - until next time.